# asp.net generating onclick event automatically for button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

ASP.NET seems to be generating its own onclick event for any buttons that are generated.

Looks like this

javascript:__doPostBack(

This is preventing jQuery from working correctly.

Does anyone know how to stop asp.net engine from doing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a **return false** to your jquery code that handles the button.

```
$("myaspbutton").click(function(e){

   //your code

   return false;****
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Buttton runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="MyButton" OnClientClick="alert('hi');" />
```

**Update:**
you can bind the click event dynamically:

```
$('#<%=myButton.ClientID%>').click(function(e) {
//your code here
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I've even tried 
e.defaultValue = false;